# How do you get the ephemeral port number of a client in ASP .NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, tcp

I would like to track client sessions by connection (not session state or cookies) in ASP .NET. I was planning on doing this by using the client's IP address and [ephemeral port number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

You can get the IPAddress in ASP .NET via

- `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVairables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.

Neither of which give you the reply port number. Is there another way to get it? Is it even possible?

Comment: @Marc B, this looks promising... you should probably post it as an answer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Heh, whaddhaya know. I was just taking a wild stab in the dark... One answer, coming right up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_PORT"].
                                                    ^^^^
```

perhaps?

Comment: If you have a client/server setup, to get the client base address, use the following:
// http://localhost:50899
            string clientServer = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ORIGIN"];

Comment: @LeviFuller HTTP should be client/server per definition, right? This question / answer is not about getting the base address, so I think you might have posted your comment in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this for regular web browsing because HTTP connections between the client and the server are not long lived.

For example IIS7 specifies a default idle timeout of 120s after which the connection will be torn down.

The next time your browser connects to the server the "ephemeral" port number will most likely have changed (because it's chosen randomly).

Comment: @brandon - so I'm interested....how are you going to track sessions if the port changes all the time?

Comment: Well.. This is for a diagnostic tool. I'm creating a page on this web server to show who's connected and how many connections each consumer has open. I also want to know things like the frequency of their communication and their user-agent.

Unless IIS gives me a way to query connections it manages I'm stuck with guessing that a unique IP + port combo means a separate connection if it has seen activity in the last 120 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current HTTP context:
<sub>If you're doing this in an MVC controller, you can instead use the controller's `HttpContext` property directly.</sub>

```
var context = HttpContext.Current as IServiceProvider;
```

Next, get the HTTP worker request:

```
var request = context.GetService(
    typeof(HttpWorkerRequest)) as HttpWorkerRequest;
```

Then you can get the client's ephemeral port number like this:

```
var port = request.GetRemotePort();
```

Answer (score -3):

This works perfectly.

```
string portNo = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
```

You can visit this:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Comment: For your information: I think you got downvoted for posting an answer that is pretty much identical to the one posted almost a half year before your own.

Comment: ... also, your answer seems to be about the server port, and not the client port as requested.